# How to run code in TimerTask regualarly

Tags: android, timer, timertask

I use this code to run my code regularly ,

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
             public void run() {        
               runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  @Override
                public void run() {

                //my code here
                         }
                      });
                  }
            }, 0, 50);
```

There is a parameter of timer receives Date object to run code in specifec date, But
I need to Run my code with timertask every friday of week, 
Any way?

Afakomoallah, Best regards.

Comment: Use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html)

Comment: Please give me another reference, developer.android.com is not available for our country.

Comment: Use AlarmManger as bhargavg suggested. Use this http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/use-androids-alarmmanager-to-schedule-an-event/

Also just curious which country are you from

Comment: I saw sample of using AlarmManager, Like TimerTask we can give a specifef time to do something, But How should I Implement to do something I every Friday of week?